# Make Bootstrap panel content div stretch to 100% of it's parent with no hardcoded values

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

Can't figure out how to make

```
<div class="panel-body">
```

to stretch to full parent div's height with no hardcoded values, e.g. not using something like "padding: 40px", or margin, or calc(100% - 40px), etc.

The panel is meant to house a tree that may vary in height depending on the user opening and closing folder, so i want to stretch the panel to 100% of space left and have a scrollbar.

Hoping to get a solution working on at least IE11.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ph">Page Header</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel header</div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-y: scroll">
            Variable height content
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success">
                Save
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

html,body{height:100%;}

.ph {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.container {
    height:100%;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3v4vo2c4/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `height` of the parent of your `.panel-body` and the `height` of your `.panel-body` in order to get that.

```
.panel {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-heading {
  height: 7%;
}

.panel-body {
  height: 84%;
}

.panel-footer {
  height: 9%;
}
```

[See Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju_Oliveira/t5cpw8oo/)

**Working on**: IE11, Chrome 58, FF 53 and Edge 38

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please try to resize the window vertically, you will see "Save" button being cropped. Probably because of numbers like 90% and 84%.

Comment: You can apply an `height` in percentage(%) for `.panel-heading` and `.panel-footer`, but it willl only work until a certain extent, since resizing the window will resize the container, but at certain point the content of the heading and footer will get out of the place since they are getting resized

Comment: You can work with pixels for `height` value, but you´ll have to get the window size by JavaScript in order to know the exact size you have for the container to ocupy the whole page

Comment: or you can still use percentages, but work also with media queries and change `height` value for smaller screens